# STD::FUNCTION C++

Tags: c++11

I'm still learning Modern C++ and I would like to clarify STD:FUNCTION,
Here is my sample code that works fine :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int func(function<bool()> foo) {
    return 2;
}

struct fee {
    bool operator()() {
        return true;
    }    
};

int main() {
    cout << func(fee());
}
```

It will display "2" on the console.

What I am wondering is why this does not work. I changed `bool operator()()` to `bool operator()(int i)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int func(function<bool()> foo) {
    return 2;
}

struct fee {
    bool operator()(int i) {
        return true;
    }    
};

int main() {
    cout << func(fee());
}
```

The error says:

```
In function 'int main()':
18:20: error: could not convert 'fee()' from 'fee' to 'std::function<bool()>'
```

What should be the right thing to do ?

Comment: `int func(function<bool(int)> foo) {`

Comment: `function<bool()> foo` means that the function/functor must be callable with no arguments, and returns `bool`

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, the fee operator() function now takes an `int` as a parameter.

Therefore you need to change

```
int func(function<bool()> foo) {
    return 2;
}
```

to

```
int func(function<bool(int)> foo) {
    return 2;
}
```

to reflect that.